# Connect two places 400 meters away at 10 Gigabit

Tags: networking

we are a small media company with 10 gigabit networking using a couple Netgear Switches and CAT6 Ethernet to all the computers in our office.

We expanded to a new location recently which is around 400 meters away. And we need atleast a single link at 10 Gigabit at this place.

Line of Sight is possible but we might lose in near future as new constructions are happening mid way.

I've been thinking of Fiber Cables with SFP+ or media converters at both ends. But not sure of how to execute this or whether this would be the ideal way.
Also not sure of the permissions required here in Hyderabad, India to run fiber optic.

Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: If there is the possibility of construction between the two sites, you need to acquire an easement for your cabling, otherwise it could be destroyed by the construction. You really need to get a professional to do this for you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Fiber optic cable (single mode) is probably the cheaper and more reliable option. However, I can't speak to any issue regarding the installation/procurement of fiber optic cable.  You will have to contact local authorities for that.